# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object Cannot deserialize the current JSON object with group column

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am calling the API and trying to store the Jsonresult into a IEnumerable model class. The json result has group header column consolidated_weather.
when I run the program the following error is coming

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object  into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`.

How can I call the given json result into the IEnumerable model class after avoiding group header from json result.

I am using the following two model.

```
 public class Weather
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string weather_state_name { get; set; }
    public string weather_state_abbr { get; set; }
    public string wind_direction_compass { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime applicable_date { get; set; }
    public decimal min_temp { get; set; }
    public decimal max_temp { get; set; }
    public decimal the_temp { get; set; }
    public double wind_speed { get; set; }
    public decimal wind_direction { get; set; }
    public decimal air_pressure { get; set; }
    public decimal Humidity { get; set; }
    public string  Visibllity { get; set; }
    public decimal Predictability { get; set; } 
   }
 public class WeatherList
{
    public IEnumerable<Weather> consolidated_weather { get; set; }
}
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Weather>> GetWeatherAsync(string woied)
    {

        var url = SD.APIBaseUrl + woied;
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
       
        IEnumerable<Weather> weather = new List<Weather>();
        WeatherList weatherList = new WeatherList();
        
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherList>(jsonString);
            return weatherList;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The API result is coming as

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    {
        "consolidated_weather": [
            {
                "id": 4577625064341504,
                "weather_state_name": "Heavy Rain",
                "weather_state_abbr": "hr",
                "wind_direction_compass": "WSW",
                "created": "2020-07-14T19:35:14.577740Z",
                "applicable_date": "2020-07-14",
                "min_temp": 11.11,
                "max_temp": 15.05,
                "the_temp": 14.32,
                "wind_speed": 6.570953330777592,
                "wind_direction": 254.13274105640758,
                "air_pressure": 1016.5,
                "humidity": 85,
                "visibility": 7.654361031575599,
                "predictability": 77
            },
            {
                "id": 4896540210495488,
                "weather_state_name": "Showers",
                "weather_state_abbr": "s",
                "wind_direction_compass": "WNW",
                "created": "2020-07-14T19:35:17.569534Z",
                "applicable_date": "2020-07-15",
                "min_temp": 12.31,
                "max_temp": 17.03,
                "the_temp": 16.509999999999998,
                "wind_speed": 7.600821124862802,
                "wind_direction": 284.49357944800784,
                "air_pressure": 1015.5,
                "humidity": 82,
                "visibility": 13.558008729022509,
                "predictability": 73
            },
]
"title": "Texas",
    "location_type": "City", 
    "timezone": "US"
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Hi, I think "null" might be related with your jsonString. The jsonString you post first is not completed. Did you shorten it on purpose or it is the whole string?

Comment: I suggest you can test jsonString from my code to deserialize WeatherList  object as our way firstly. If success as us, then you could check the jsonString API.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code. The JSON string is truncated, the method returns `IEnumerable<Weather>` but the code returns a single `WeatherList` and the `weather` variable is never used. This wouldn't even compile, much less produce an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your json string, we can see that there is a list of `weather` object in object `consolidated_weather`.
So you need to parse json to WeatherList.

```
public class WeatherList {
        public IEnumerable<Weather> consolidated_weather { get; set; }
    }


[HttpPost("/weather")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Weather>> GetWeatherAsync()
    {

        string jsonString = "{\"consolidated_weather\":[{\"id\":4577625064341504,\"weather_state_name\":\"Heavy Rain\",\"weather_state_abbr\":\"hr\",\"wind_direction_compass\":\"WSW\",\"created\":\"2020-07-14T19:35:14.577740Z\",\"applicable_date\":\"2020-07-14\",\"min_temp\":11.11,\"max_temp\":15.05,\"the_temp\":14.32,\"wind_speed\":6.570953330777592,\"wind_direction\":254.13274105640758,\"air_pressure\":1016.5,\"humidity\":85,\"visibility\":7.654361031575599,\"predictability\":77},{\"id\":4896540210495488,\"weather_state_name\":\"Showers\",\"weather_state_abbr\":\"s\",\"wind_direction_compass\":\"WNW\",\"created\":\"2020-07-14T19:35:17.569534Z\",\"applicable_date\":\"2020-07-15\",\"min_temp\":12.31,\"max_temp\":17.03,\"the_temp\":16.509999999999998,\"wind_speed\":7.600821124862802,\"wind_direction\":284.49357944800784,\"air_pressure\":1015.5,\"humidity\":82,\"visibility\":13.558008729022509,\"predictability\":73}]}";
        IEnumerable<Weather> weather = new List<Weather>();


        WeatherList weatherList = new WeatherList();
        weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherList>(jsonString);

        return weatherList.consolidated_weather;

    }
```

> Test Result

[image]

UPDATE

---

```
 public class WeatherList 
 {
    public IEnumerable<Weather> consolidated_weather { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    
 }
```

There are two missings in your `json` string:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    {
        "consolidated_weather": [
            {
                "id": 4577625064341504,
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 4896540210495488,
                ...
            },
] <!-- missing , -->
"title": "Texas",
    "location_type": "City", 
    "timezone": "US"
<!-- missing } -->

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: I did the same way but still not working. the error message is coming 'cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.Generic.Ienumerable<Weather>.

Comment: Hi, could you update your code? so that I can help with that.

Comment: Michelle I forgot to add 'Title' 'Location Type' that column should be ignored from the string . please can you check my updated post

Comment: That's reason you didn't  deserialize Object well. It must be same as json format. Add other attributes to WeatherList, then it will works well.

Comment: Please can you give your updated code for the solution .

Comment: The `weather` variable is never used

Comment: That's true. As @Panagiotis mentioned, you should return  {return weatherList.consolidated_weather; } not {return weatherList;} in the end of action.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot change the content of the Json, you can create a ConsolidatedWeather class that contains the List of Weathers

```
public class ConsolidatedWeather
{
    public List<Weather> Consolidated_Weather { get; set; }
}
```

and in your deserialize part

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsolidatedWeather>(jsonString).Consolidated_Weather;
```